# Where can I find information on the "themed trail" in Lauterbrunnen Valley?

Tags: switzerland, hiking, walking

I found mention of an interesting walking trail on the [Switzerland tourism site](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en-us/lauterbrunnen.html):

> UNESCO world heritage themed trail in the depths of the Lauterbrunnen
>   Valley, the first themed trail in the Junggfrau-Aletsch-Bietschhorn
>   world natural heritage site and devoted to waterfalls, alpine farming,
>   power stations and mountain hotels.

It even has [its own page](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en-us/theme-trail-in-unesco-world-heritage-region.html) dedicated to it.  However neither of those has detailed information on the trail, and I'm not having any luck Googling it presumably because I don't really know what to search for (my attempts just keep taking me back to those websites).

I'm specifically looking for information like a map, distances and how to get to it.

Comment: Well there's this: http://mylauterbrunnen.com/11/14/564/en/Holidays/SUMMER/Hiking/Isenfluh_-_Sulwald/Isenfluh-Sulwald-Suls-Lobhornhutte__2%3A30_h -- sadly the map link is broken but it has an e-mail address there you could mail ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This attraction really has very very bad documentation. I would not blame your google skills for this. Unfortunately, the information is English is very bad, but not much better in German.

The problem is that some years ago, all the villages had their own websites with such information, and then closed them and consolidated all to the regional and national pages. In that process, a lot of information must have been lost.

I found this [PDF dedicating a half-pag](http://www.lch.ch/dms-static/6c09d230-2fab-430b-a52e-f65e0ef21c19/rz_23.pdf)e to the trail, with unfortunately not much more information on it. Some more information was to be found [on page 11 of this PDF here](http://jungfrauregion.ch/cmsfiles/lauterbrunnen_de.pdf), where they mention that the path starts in Stechelberg. That village still has it's own [website with a subsection](http://www.stechelberg.ch/sehen-und-erleben/sommer/unesco-erlebnispfade.html) dedicated to the trail. Those are also all in German however. This [Google translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.stechelberg.ch/sehen-und-erleben/sommer/unesco-erlebnispfade.html) should be enough I hope. There is more information on site in pamphlets available.  If you need more concrete information I would strongly suggest you call or email the tourist office that is listed on the website. I am sure they speak English well enough to answer the most important questions.

On top of that, I can strongly recommend you the website [bergfex](http://www.bergfex.com/sommer/jungfrau-region/touren/). They list the most famous trails in the area with GPS, height and more information.

Comment: `all the villages had their own websites with such information, and then closed them and consolidated all to the regional and national pages. In that process, a lot of information must have been lost.` = the story of so many bad ideas... :(

Comment: @dlanod yeah but some of the village websites were really, really bad and untouched for decades. And even the good ones that are leftover are almost impossible to find.